# How to show the last list elements to a user if an exception occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, c#-4.0

For my website i don't want the user to encounter any exceptions if they do occur say i have a List of all the app.

```
 public static List<IndianAppStore_TopRated_Result> GetTopRatedApps()
{
    //  logger.Info("Start--GetTopRatedApps"); 

    try  /// aatif
    {
        objTopList = admin.GetTopRatedApps().Take(6).ToList();
        if (objTopList.Count <= 0)
        {
            objTopList = GetInterimApps();
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return objTopList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        logger.Error("CatchData.GetTopRatedApps()" + ex.StackTrace); 
        return objTopList;
    }
    // logger.Info("End--GetTopRatedApps"); 
}
```

If in case any error occurs or the list of apps is equal to 0 i want the user to be shown the Last list of apps that were present.

Can this be done with a static list?

Comment: How can the list of apps be less than 0?

Comment: Don't use `static` data with ASP.NET - it's shared across all users.

Comment: want it to be shared across users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by putting a copy of the last successfully-retrieved list in the ASP.NET `Cache`, for instance:

```
objTopList = admin.GetTopRatedApps().Take(6).ToList();
if (objTopList.Count == 0)
{
    objTopList = (MyListType) Cache["TopList"];
} else {
    Cache["TopList"] = objTopList;
}
```

Comment: No. Page invocations do not survive multiple requests and so your static list would be empty every time.

Comment: What if it is inside a Class inside App_Code?

Comment: That makes no difference. You can look up the function of App_Code and the other folders on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx.

Comment: Hi thanks can i use memory cache instead of web caching if i want to display the same info to multiple users in case there is no data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41694/discussion-between-vini-and-roy-dictus)